# How to implement an external script file in an Angular component?

Tags: angular, api, components

I am using an external api in my angular project. When I am using normal HTML/Javascript file all I have to do is:

```
<script src="http://api.eventful.com/js/api"></script>
<script>

EVDB.API.call("/events/get", argument, function(oData) {
      alert("your myObject is " + JSON.stringify(oData) );
    });}
</script>
```

To get the data I want.
So in my components typescipt file I have:

```
myFunc(argument) {
  EVDB.API.call('/events/search', argument, function(oData) {
    alert('your myObject is ' + JSON.stringify(oData));
  });
}
```

I added `<script src="http://api.eventful.com/js/api"></script>`in my index.html and put "http://api.eventful.com/js/api" under my scripts array in the angular.json file.

Despite this, I keep getting and error that says "Identifier 'EVDB' is not defined. Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add it to both angular.json and index.html. Angular.json is only for local scripts you want to include, not applicable in your case.
I'm assuming that the script is defining a global variable called EVDB. To use it in a typescript class, you need to declare it:

`declare var EVDB;`

... should do the trick.

Also make sure that the script include is above your main `<client-app>` entry point in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<script src="http://api.eventful.com/js/api"></script>` to index.html.

Add `declare var EVDB:any;` at every place you have use `EVDB` object but if you have use  it in the entier project create `global.d.ts`in src folder and add the statement  `declare var EVDB:any;` to the file this way `EVDB` object will be avilable in the entier project.

it's better to add extra information about `EVDB` object type like this

```
interface RestApi {
    call:(url:string,args:any,callback:(args?:any)=> void) => void
}

interface EVDBType {
    api:RestApi
}

declare var EVDB :EVDBType;
```